# npm install couchbase contacts http

Tags: node.js

I noticed that when I do `npm install couchbase` its contacting `http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.12.6/node-v0.12.6.tar.gz`.  when I do `npm congig get registry` I see we use `https`: `https://registry.npmjs.org/`

questions:

1. why does `npm install couchbase` contacts `http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.12.6/node-v0.12.6.tar.gz` and not `https://nodejs.org/dist/v0.12.6/node-v0.12.6.tar.gz`
2. is it possible to force it to contcat `https`?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What version of `node` and `npm` do you have? How did you notice that it downloads http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.12.6/node-v0.12.6.tar.gz? I'm wondering why `npm` would download `node` itself, and such an old version at that.

For me, when I run:

```
npm i couchbase --verbose 2>&1 | grep http:
```

I don't get anything. On the other hand this:

```
npm i couchbase --verbose 2>&1 | grep https: | wc -l
```

gives me 833 results (which is quite a few requests to install one module, but all of them are HTTPS). This is the same on `node` 5.12.0 with `npm` 3.8.6 and on `node` 6.5.0 with `npm` 3.10.3 (though 6.5 makes even more requests than 5.12, but still no HTTP).